# Unable to turn off dl.google repos in SDK manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

Being in China sometimes dl.google repos are just not usable and will take forever to fetch. So I prefer to turn them off and use third party mirrors. But it doesn't seem to be possible to untick them in SDK manager. Is there some way I can do this manually (possibly via modifying some config file in the system?)

[image]

Comment: Not sure how far you can go with the command line SDK manager? That might provide a different method of customization.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be able to configure this via the command line SDK manager at all.